# Customize events handling of an asp.net user-control depending on the calling form

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I'm using an asp.net user-control in two different aspx forms. How can I customize the events handling of the user-control depending on the calling form ?

```
void ComboboxCountry_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, RadComboBoxSelectedIndexChangedEventArgs e)
  {
            if it is form1 that called the User-control => do process 1

            if it is form2 that called the User-control => do process 2
  }
```

Thanks.

Comment: You can acess to calling form using `(Control)sender.Parent`

Comment: I don't have the property "Parent" for the object "sender" . Maybe I missed something?

Comment: `((Control)sender).Parent` - my mistake, missed braces.

Comment: Indeed. Can I retrieve the calling Form ID to identify the Form into the User-control? IF ((Control)sender).Parent.ID = "xxxx" ), where can I get the ID then? Or maybe I should use another property than the ID.

Comment: You can access it via .Name property

Comment: Do you mean .NamingContainer property?

Comment: No, I mean ((Control)sender).Parent.Name property.
See this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control_properties.aspx

Comment: Ah ok, you are talking about "Control" class from System.Windows.Forms, I use System.Web.UI namespace !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the fact if this is a good design you are trying to implement: you could add a property to your control like

```
public BehaviourEnum Behaviour { get; set; } // You need to implement the enum
```

Then you could

```
void ComboboxCountry_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, RadComboBoxSelectedIndexChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (Behaviour == BehaviourEnum.Behave1) // etc.
}
```

The pages implementing your control would need to set the Behaviour-Property accordingly.

Edit: If your control needs to interact with the parent page, I would introduce an interface on the parents page. Then you could design something like this:

```
// The page containing this control needs to implement IMasterpage
public IMasterpage Masterpage { get; set; } 

void ComboboxCountry_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, RadComboBoxSelectedIndexChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Propagate the behavour to your parent page
    Masterpage.CallwatheverMethodInYourInterface();
}
```

The goal is to propagate behavour which depends on the parent page into the parent page itself. That way you can keep your control slim and independent.

Comment: Do you think it is a bad design ? Can you please explain why and propose a better way to reuse User-Controls, with customized events handling? thanks

Comment: I meant it is rather bad design if the control needs to figure out his parent. The dependency should be injected from outside, you shouldn't make it depending from the outside environment. My first sentence in my answer was misleading though, that way with a property I don't consider it as bad. See also my edited answer.

Comment: I don't want to invoke the parent form methods inside of the User-control, I just want to put a condition who tells the User-control : If it is Form 1 that called you, do some stuff (for example enable some textfields in the user-control) and if it is Form2 that called => do other stuff (Ex : keep textfields disabled).

Comment: Then I might go for the first version I showed you: `if (Behaviour == BehaviourEnum.Behave1) // Enable certain fields etc.`. I wouldn't make it depending on the parent page, it leads to inflexibility.

Comment: Then I don't see the relation with the parent Form, since the public attribute 'Behaviour' and the condition  ' if (Behaviour == BehaviourEnum.Behave1)'  are both in the user-control, no condition on the parent who called...

Comment: @Believer: The parent-form defines how the control should behave: It sets the Behaviour-Property accordingly. The control itself should not be interested in what form it resides. Doesn't make sense?